# Require image from state returns error

Tags: reactjs

to learn React I created a REST API to grab data from and after some issues I got it working with fetching data in my state, and rendering the component with data depending on state.

now, i'm trying to use `this.state.data.Image`, which is a simple string like `example.jpg`, to show different images which I have stored locally in my project. the pictures are stored in the src directory while I have my components in a component directory, so to grab the picture I have to use `../example.jpg`. if i do this grab with an import, like this:

`import example from '../example.jpg';`

`<img src={example} alt=""></img>`

it all works well, but this doesn't work if i want to show the image depending on which set of data i'm grabbing from the API. so I'm trying something like this:

`<img src={require("../" + this.state.data.Image)} alt=""></img>`

`./src/App.test.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\MyName\Code\react-test\src'`

For boilerplate I use create-react-app, which is why this `App.test.js` file is generated. Why is this issue arising? Am I missing a key point? Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write `src={require("../" + this.state.data.Image)}` in jsx files.You have to import all image files as

```
import example1 from '../example1.jpg';
import example2 from '../example1.jpg';
<img src={example1} alt=""></img>
```

based on `this.state.data.Image` you can import images

You can create a map as

```
   imageMap = ["img1":{example1},
    "img2":{example2}

]
```

and write

```
const inputImg = this.state.data.Image
<img src={imgMap[inputImg]} alt=""></img>
```

Comment: Oh, okay. But I can't use state while importing so how should I know which file to import? Or should I import all my pictures, and with if-conditions decide what to put in `<img src="">`?

Comment: All right. What I did was import all my pictures and created a `getImg` function which showed the corresponding image in the `src=""` tag depending on what the image-string is. But, surely, there should be a faster and more dynamic way?